# Appropriate collection type for selecting a random element efficiently in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For a project I am working on, I need to keep track of up to several thousand objects.  The collection I choose needs to support insertion, selection, and deletion of random elements.  My algorithm performs each of these operations several times, so I would like a collection that can do all these in constant time.

Is there such a collection?  If not, what are some trade-offs with existing collections?  I am using Scala 2.9.1.

**EDIT:** By "random", I mean mathematically/probabilistically random, i.e., I would like to select elements randomly from the collection using Random or some other appropriate generator.

Comment: Should your collection be able to contain duplicates? Is the order of elements of relevance?

Comment: @PeterSchmitz, I will not be trying to store duplicates, and the order of elements does not matter as I only want to access them randomly.

Comment: Several thousand objects isn't much, not even for 10 y'old hardware. 'Several times' is a vague term too. Probably every collection would be fine for you.

Comment: @userunknown, you're right, I might not have to worry about it.  However, I would still like to use a collection that minimizes the running time.

Comment: here's a [performance-wise comparison of scala collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html). Pick your choice base also on the programming style you prefer (functional? "Pure" OOP?) and how parallel the access to your collection needs to be (do you have only one thread accessing it?).

Comment: Please tell us once you've found the collection that does all the mentioned things in constant time.

Comment: Can you clarify the operations you need -- for example what is an insertion of a random element? Isn't it sufficient if you either add elements at random indices or pull pull elements from random indices, instead of asking for both? Because then you can choose a data structure that support efficient append or prepend along with efficient random access and removal, or vice versa. Do you need an immutable or a mutable data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "random". If you mean indexed, then there's no such collection. You can have insertion/deletion in constant time if you give up the "random element" requirement -- ie, you have have non-constant lookup of the element which will be deleted or which will be the point of insertion. Or you can have constant lookup without constant insertion/deletion.

The collection that best approaches that requirement is the `Vector`, which provides `O(log n)` for these operations.

On the other hand, if you have the element which you'll be looking up or removing, then just pick a `HashMap`. It's not *precisely* constant time, but it is a fair approximation. Just make sure you have a good hash function.

Comment: Until recently I thought that because `Vector` is an `IndexedSeq`, it was like an immutable array, but actually it's a tree. This helps explain its performance characteristics. Full Vector description here: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_15.html

Comment: I think a `HashMap` is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, take a look at [The Scala 2.8 Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html) especially at `Performance Characteristics`.